# Replacing out-of-bounds (complex) values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

(Python 2.7, pandas 0.13.0)

Background: I read in a bunch of data from a CSV file and load it into a pandas dataframe.  Some of the data is complex (I convert it from strings when loading).  Some of the values were equipment errors, distinguished by by being too big.  I want to replace all the values whose magnitude is above a certain threshold with np.nan.  This is easy with a numpy array (provided you use a "complex nan" as shown), but has been challenging in pandas.  I've documented the steps I've tried below - the last attempt almost gets there, but any row where a replacement occurs is converted to real.

At this point I'm think of simply pulling the values into a numpy array, modifying, and then loading back into the dataframe, but that seems rather inelegant.

EDIT:  The solution below works, but I'm wondering if there's still a bug <s>in the way pandas handles NaN.</s> in the code I wrote.  It looks like the NaN created is `nan +0.j` instead of `nan +nanj`.  <s>Matplotlib will graph the latter without a problem if you're doing something like `plot(np.real(signal), np.imag(signal))`, but does not like the former since it's plotting a (Nan, 0) pair.  It looks like I need to substitute the new `nan +0j` entries with `nan +nanj` entries, which recursively restarts the problem. :)</s>

EDIT2: There does appear to be a visual difference in the NaN's, but the new bug I found was unrelated to that difference.  The difference is probably unimportant.  Incorrect things above struckthrough.

```
# begin by making a fake data set that resembles the CSV struction
headers = ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3']
temp = np.arange(12).reshape((4,3)) + 1j*np.arange(12,24).reshape((4,3))
temp[0,1] = 5000 + 1j*5000
temp[1,1] = 5000 + 1j*8000
temp[2,2] = 7000 + 1j*3000
junk = ['exists to', 'make life', 'extra', 'difficult']
df_junk = pd.DataFrame(data=junk, columns=['other junk'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=temp, columns=headers)
df = pd.concat((df, df_junk), axis=1)
# very simple to do this in an np.array if we only take the numbers
temp2 = np.copy(temp)
# temp2 is the desired result, but in the frame with everything else
temp2[ np.abs(temp2) > 5000 ] = np.nan + 1j*np.nan
df2 = df.copy()

# Executing the next line replaces the value with NaN,
# but turns all of column Z2 into real numbers
#df[np.abs(df[headers]) > 5000 ] = np.nan + 1j*np.nan
# Trying to grab the index first gives
# ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
#df.ix[np.abs(df[headers]) > 5000 ]
for column in headers:
    # The following line would turn the entire 3rd row into NaN
    # df[np.abs(df[column]) > 5000] = np.nan + 1j*np.nan
    # Attempts along these lines to apply a lambda (tried different ones)
    # didn't seem to work
    #csv_data[column] = csv_data[column].apply(lambda x:\
    # pd.replace(x, np.nan) if abs(x) > 5000 else pd.replace(x,x))
    # This last one almost works, but again turns columns with replacements into reals
    df2[column].where(abs(df2[column]) <= 5000, np.nan+1j*np.nan, inplace=True)

        Z1  Z2  Z3 other junk
0      12j NaN   2  exists to
1  (3+15j) NaN   5  make life
2  (6+18j)   7 NaN      extra
3  (9+21j)  10  11  difficult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this works without the inplace flag:

```
In [11]: df3 = df2[['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3']]

In [12]: df3.where(df3 <= 5000)  # replaces by NaN by default
Out[12]:
        Z1        Z2        Z3
0      12j       NaN   (2+14j)
1  (3+15j)       NaN   (5+17j)
2  (6+18j)   (7+19j)       NaN
3  (9+21j)  (10+22j)  (11+23j)

In [13]: df2[['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3']] = df3.where(df3 <= 5000)
```

*Generally I think avoiding the inplace flag is a good idea (although this is probably a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6345)):*

```
In [21]: df3.where(df3 <= 5000, inplace=True)

In [22]: df3
Out[22]:
        Z1  Z2  Z3
0      12j NaN   2
1  (3+15j) NaN   5
2  (6+18j)   7 NaN
3  (9+21j)  10  11
```

Comment: this is excatly the same as: ``df3[df3<=5000] = np.nan`` and in fact how it is implemented

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, think there is a bug there :s

Comment: hmm....ok...well you noted it as a bug! complex is the long-lost child right now...

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the quick response, and somewhat glad to know the initial numpy-like code should have worked.  Is there any objection to one-lining it with no extra variables - and do I save an extra dataframe floating around in memory?  E.g., `df[headers] = df.where(np.abs(df[headers]) <= 5000)[headers]`

Comment: @schodge yeah that's ok too, you can `del df3` after the operation so I suspect it'll be much of a muchness in terms of memory (you may have copied in memory til they're gc'd). :)

Comment: @AndyHayden Could you look at the edit I made?  I think in some ways I'm back to the original problem - it looks like pandas is inserting a float nan and I need a complex nan...? (Oxymoronic I think).

Comment: @AndyHayden Added one more edit.  The NaN's look different, but they weren't the cause of the new bug I found, so I don't know if they make any difference.

Comment: @schodge I think this should probably be a separate question, or a comment on the github issue? You can replace with nan + jnan explicitly with: `df3.where(df3 <= 5000, nan+jnan)`, the default is nan.